# How to change toolbar in recyclerview when item is longclicked?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to delete items in recyclerview. 
I expect change toolbar shape when i longclick.
I did that using visibility, it work sucessful but I'm not sure this way is right.

**this is toolbar.xml using databinding.**

```
<data>        
    <import type = "android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name = "isDeleteToolbar"
        type = "boolean"/>
</data>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id = "@+id/toolbar_search"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    >        
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        cardView:cardElevation = "2dp"
        >            
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:gravity = "center"
            android:orientation = "horizontal"
            >                
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
                android:visibility = "@{ isDeleteToolbar ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE }"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id = "@+id/text_toolbar_search"
                android:layout_width = "0dp"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:visibility = "@{ !isDeleteToolbar ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE }"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id = "@+id/text_toolbar_search_count"
                android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight = "1"    
                android:visibility = "@{ isDeleteToolbar ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE }"
                />

        </LinearLayout>             
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**it's fragment.xml**

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width = "match_parent"
      android:layout_height = "match_parent"
          >
     <include
        android:id = "@+id/toolbar"
        style = "@style/ConstraintTop"
        layout = "@layout/toolbar_search"
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        />
    ...
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**and this is fragment. it handles recyclerview's item longclick event.**

```
    adapter.getPublishSubject()
            .subscribe(data -> {
                binding.toolbar.setIsDeleteToolbar(true);
            });
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: I think this is a bad idea. you should set a listener for list item. Then in listener change toolbar visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is to Create Toolbar ActionMode

```
ActionMode mActionMode;
Menu context_menu;
```

**ActionMode:**

```
 private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
        MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.muliselect, menu);
        context_menu = menu;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_delete:

                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
        mActionMode = null;
        isMultiSelect = false;
        selectEmailArrayList = new ArrayList<Email>();
        refreshAdapter();

    }
};
```

**On ListView LongClick Listener do:**

```
@Override
public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
    if (!isMultiSelect) {
        selectEmailArrayList = new ArrayList<Email>();
        isMultiSelect = true;

        if (mActionMode == null) {
            mActionMode = startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
        }
    }
    multi_select(position);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented the Action mode in your reyclerview adapter, then this is how you set the toolbar colour when the user long presses and gets into the Action mode:

Place this code inside your activity theme in the values-v21/styles.xml file

```
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Here @color/colorAccent is the reference to the colour that I want the toolbar colour to change to. Place your desired colour here.